# API fetch from PVGIS with javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm in pursue of solution how to fetch data from API "PVGIS" (https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/) using vanilla javascript and process data for futher calcualtions

when accessing api from browser js script i get an "CORS policy error"
when accessing API from standalone node.js script i can fetch a data

here is fetch function from node that outputs data correctly

```
async function fetchData() {
    const data = await fetch('https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/PVcalc?lat=45&lon=8&peakpower=1&loss=14&outputformat=json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json.outputs.monthly)
        })
}
```

as i understand, i should be building a backend server side with api request to pvgis and then connecting it with my front js side to process the data ... is this a correct path?
Can you give me some details how to get going ?

here is the GUI of this api
https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/tools.html

and API documentation
https://joint-research-centre.ec.europa.eu/pvgis-online-tool/getting-started-pvgis/api-non-interactive-service_en

Comment: Do you need a backend for any other purpose? You don't need a backend to just request data from an API. However if you want to store data in a database, process the data on server side, use websockets or something like that, you'd need a backend.

Answer (score 0):

As the website says, they are not making this API's available for use in browser

> Warning: access to PVGIS APIs via AJAX is not allowed. Please, do not ask for changes in our CORS policy since these requests will be rejected by the system administrators.

They basically have CORS policy which blocks any other origin to make request. Cors is basically browser security mechanism. But as you mentioned you can access it through script since its not in browser.
Also as they mentioned, they have rate limiters so you can not call api every second.
Way to go here would be to have backend script on nodeJS which calls api, gets data and saves it in your database and then you would have another api endpoint, that queries this data from database. Also add some cron job, which would schedule request to get newer data from api every hour or so, so your db data does not go stale